# Exam class: Change distance (space) between questions

Tags: spacing, exam

I am looking for a way to change (increase) the spacing between `\question` items within a `\question` environment (shown in red). I was only able to change the distance between the title and the items.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with some compilable code that produced the output above. That is, please add a minimal working example to your question, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and illustrates the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You could use \vspace{\stretch{1}} after each part of the parts environment (or \vspace{} and some length, e.g. \vspace{0.2cm}, if you want to determine the vertical space).